# Can't find interface code generation option in SharpDevelop 4.1

Tags: code-generation, sharpdevelop

This seems like a stupid issue, but I can't seem to find an option to generate interface code with in the newest SharpDevelop build. When I search the site I get a lot of mentions of Alt+Ins and the Tools menu but those options do not appear to be available in the newest build. I can right click and extract interfaces but there doesn't seem to be any option to stub them in. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SharpDevelop 4.1 put the mouse cursor on the class name or on the interface name. You will then see an icon appear on the left hand side of the text editor.

[image: Implement interface - class or interface selected]

Then press Ctrl+T to display a pop-up menu.

[image: Implement interface - pop-up menu]

This will give you a list of interfaces you can implement. Select the appropriate interface using the up and down arrows and press the Enter key. Then code will be generated for that interface.

[image: Generated interface code]

Whenever you see this icon you can generate code. For more information on this feature take a look at the [New productivity features blog post](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/martinkonicek/archive/2010/08/01/resharper-for-sharpdevelop-new-features.aspx) by Martin Konicek.